# Ignorar o cabeçalho ao inserir dados de um arquivo csv em um vetor de string Java

Tags: java, string, csv, conversão-de-tipo

Boa noite,

Fiz a leitura de um arquivo csv e armazenei as informações em um vetor de string. O arquivo da posição 0 a 8 possui conteúdo de string, da posição 9 a 29 possui em seu conteúdo inteiros. 
Preciso comparar se o conteúdo da posição 9 a 29 é diferente de 0 , para isso precisei converter o meu vetor de string em um vetor de inteiros da posição 9 a 29, porém, está dando o erro justamente com a descrição da coluna 9:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Coluna9"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

Portanto, para resolver esse erro, creio que preciso ignorar a linha 1.
Como faço para começar preencher o vetor a partir da segunda linha?
Abaixo código que lê o csv e faz a conversão para o vetor de inteiros:

```
private static final String VIRGULA = ",";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Desktop/workspace/geral/src/teste.csv")));
    String linha = null;

    while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] dados = linha.split(VIRGULA);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dados));


         int[] valorInteiros = new int[dados.length];

        for (int i = 9; i < dados.length; i++) {
            valorInteiros[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dados[i]));
            System.out.println(valorInteiros[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
    reader.close();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADR, já pensou em colocar a primeira leitura de linha antes do while? Confesso que não é muito elegante, mas acredito que soluciona o seu problema sem gerar problemas em sua lógica:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  private static final String VIRGULA = ",";

  public static int converteInteiro(String valor) {
    try {
      return Integer.parseInt(valor);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("teste.csv")));
    String linha = null;

    if (reader.readLine() != null) {
      while ((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] dados = linha.split(VIRGULA);
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dados));

          int[] valorInteiros = new int[dados.length];

          for (int i = 9; i < dados.length; i++) {
              valorInteiros[i] = converteInteiro(String.valueOf(dados[i]));
              System.out.println(valorInteiros[i]);
          }

          System.out.println("--------------------------");
      }
    }
    reader.close();
  }
}
```

Veja funcionando aqui:
https://repl.it/repls/RedInstructiveCrash

Comment: Deu certo, porém , no final da execução deu o seguinte erro:
    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at geral.Main.main(Main.java:26)
 

a linha 26 refere: 
          valorInteiros[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(dados[i]));

Porque será?

Comment: Precisa verificar o seu CSV, talvez ele tenha algum valor que não está de acordo, coloca ele aí pra gente analisar.

Comment: Verdade, é o csv, tem algumas colunas que não estão preenchidas com inteiro, está sem nada, assim , não consegue converter vazio "" para um inteiro. Tem como eu colocar um tratamento para nao dar esse exception do tipo converter " " em 0?

Comment: Dá sim, alterei o código com um exemplo, o converteInteiro retorna 0 na exceção de conversão.

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo.